# Is there any function in excel visual basic for finding a colunms range without blank rows?

Tags: excel, vba

i try find count of columns without blank rows and i write this on a text file my codes like this i can't do it

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
Dim filename As String, lineText As String
Dim myrng As Range, i, j

filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MuhBeyanname.txt"      ' sadece dosya adresi

Open filename For Output As #1

Set myrng = Range("A3", "AF5000")           

For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
lineText = ""
    For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & vbTab) & myrng.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    If lineText <> "" Then
    Print #1, Replace(Replace(lineText, ",", ""), ".", ",")
    End If
Next i
    
Close #1 End Sub
```

myrange is static in code but it must be dynamic on column rows without blank rows

Comment: Would "count of columns without blank rows" mean to determine the last column keeping data? Is this what you want accomplishing?

Comment: Yes that what i need

Comment: Then, try to understand my suggestion code and test it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not answer my clarification question, but if you need to determine the last row and last column of the active worksheet, your used range should be built in the next way:

```
   'your declarations ...
   '...
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long

   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'column A:A must have so many rows as the rest of the worksheet
   lastCol = sh.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'First row must have so many columns as the rest of the worksheet
   
   Set myrng = sh.Range("A3", sh.cells(lastRow, lastCol))

   'After that your code, starting with
   fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MuhBeyanname.txt"      ' sadece dosya adresi

   Open fileName For Output As #1
       'the rest of your code
       'of course, without Set myrng = Range("A3", "AF5000") 
       '...
```

Comment: I think OP wants to write all rows from a range into a file (dynamic column and rows) where row is not empty

Comment: @Zac : i cannot be sure that I am right, and not sure if you are right, neither... I 'translate' the text "count of columns without blank rows" and "finding columns range without blank rows" like something supporting my understanding. But I cannot be sure that I am right... I asked him for clarification, from this point of view but he does not say anything. Will see what he needs only after he will replay or test the code. Supposing that he will understand what i wanted to point out...

Comment: @Zac : It looks that I was right... He qualified my supposition (on my comment) being right. It looks that non English native speakers understand each other better then real speakers... :)

Comment: "finding columns range without blank rows" that what i mean, and this example helpful for me it's not figured out yet but i got it thanks

Comment: @Yusuf Selim Göl: Try please to use it as I write in comments. Use your existing code, insert my suggested one between your declarations and `filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MuhBeyanname.txt"` and then delete your row `Set myrng = Range("A3", "AF5000")`. It should work as (I understood) you need...

Comment: I have no idea what OP wants anymore :)